# Каждые пять минут выдавать случайную строку из .txt файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, случайные-числа, таймер

Создаю бота на Python 3.8 для Telegram. Необходимо, чтобы бот каждые 5 минут выдавал сообщение, содержанием которого будет случайная строка из небольшого (10 KB) .txt файла. Каждая строка вмещает в себя небольшое текстовое сообщение на кириллице.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать подобное действие.

Comment: Я знаю php. 1) Сначало получаешь текст из файла. 2) разделяешь его, пример: ; 3) далее через рандом выбираешь и отпровляешь. sleep и while в помошь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import time

handle = open("test.txt", "r")
for line in handle:
    print(line)
    time.sleep(ваше время в секундах)
handle.close()
```

Comment: Если что это не именно для бота в телеге, но думаю суть уловите

Comment: Так же можете найти ответ тут: https://overcoder.net/q/149268/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2-python

Answer (score 1):

Вам может помочь модуль [`schedule`](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/).
С его помощью можно легко планировать какие-либо действия.

***Пример:***

```py
import random
import time
import schedule


def print_random_str():
    with open('file.txt') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    print(random.choice(lines))


def main():
    schedule.every(5).minutes.do(print_random_str)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```